# How to position view based on position of one of sibling ViewGroup's child?

Tags: android, viewgroup, scroller

Ok, the question may sound confusing. Let me explain the scenario:

Refer the image at following link, (-I wasn't able to use imgur as it is blocked in my network):
http://www.flickr.com/photos/93397745@N05/8494742266/

- I have a CustomView that extends RelativeLayout (entire black part in image)
- This CustomView contains a component at top ViewTopBar (indicated in Red in image), which extends ViewGroup & is horizontally scrollable
- The ViewTopBar contains many child views. One of 'em is an IndicatorView (orange one in image), which is positioned in ViewTopBar after doing some calculations & calling layout(l,t,r,b) in ViewTopBar's onLayout() method.
- I want a vertical 1 pixel line to be displayed below the IndicatorView. It should start just below IndicatorView & cover the entire height of CustomView. (See the green colored line in image).
- This part doesn't matter, but just for information, the blue colored part in image is another Custom ViewGroup which is pretty complex to describe. (Also, there are still a few more components that are part of CustomView but not shown in the image as its not needed for my question.)

There, I hope I have the view explained. Now what I need is that the green 1px line should move horizontally so as to stay aligned below IndicatorView whenever horizontal scrolling is done. I've currently implemented it as follows:

- Placed the 1px line as child of CustomView.
- Whenever ViewTopBar's onLayout() is called, I update the GreenLine's LayoutParams & just modify the left margin depending on IndicatorView's position.

This works fine most of the time. But sometimes, when I do left-right-left-right scroll continuously, the 1pxLine does not stay in sync with the scrolling IndicatorView (--However, once scrolling stops, it comes back into sync!) So what changes do I need to make so that the line stays in sync even during scroll operations?

Please let me know if someone has been able to do this before.

Thanks,

-Kiran

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the `IndicatorView` out of `ViewTopBar`, and together with 1px-line-view I'd include it within some container layout, which I'd put inside `CustomView` instead. That way, you could control position of this element as a whole, instead of making one 'catching-up' with another. Not sure if it's applicable in your case though.

Comment: Well, the position of IndicatorView is calculated from ViewTopBar. All of that would have to moved to CustomView for this which will complicate things in my case. Also, in this way of implementation, the 'catch-up' issue would be observed with the container-layout & children of ViewTopBar (like it is currently for IndicatorView & 1px-Line). Thanks for the inputs though.. I may end up using this if nothing else works & the 'catch-up' delay isn't too visible for container-layout! :)